# Merging two partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best Partition Manager for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/13943/best-partition-manager-for-windows)
>   [merge 3 NTFS partitions into 2 (Win XP) without reinstalling](https://superuser.com/questions/35774/merge-3-ntfs-partitions-into-2-win-xp-without-reinstalling)

I partitioned my hard drive as follows:

- C as primary
- S partition.

I would now like to have only one partition, C.

So I deleted the S partition.

How do I add this S partition, which is now deleted, to the C partition?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account in user options.

Comment: problem can be solved with one of the tools listed here: http://superuser.com/questions/13943/best-partition-manager-for-windows

Answer (score 3):

`Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Computer Management` -> `Disk Management`
Right click on the C: partition and select `Extend Volume`. Note that it must be NTFS and there must be empty space next to it to be able to extend it.

Comment: not available on all versions of Windows.

Comment: I had to right click on the S; then I could Extend the Volume
Now S is green and free space; but how does this work?
C did not extend; same size

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/). It's pretty handy and free.

Answer (score 2):

**[EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/)** helps resize, move, split and **merge partitions** without losing data.

[image]

*EASEUS Partition Master is freeware.*

Comment: Do bad; I am on a server 2003...EASEUS free version is not for server

Answer (score 1):

GParted is also a nice solution, it's available on most Linux Live CDs, especially Ubuntu. Just install it on a USB stick, boot from it, and when you're in Linux, run GParted to edit the partitions as you wish.

Comment: There's also the gparted Live-CD itself: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a third-party software like [Partion Magic](http://www.soft32.com/download_151.html)

You can download free trial but this good application is not free...

This an example among a lot of other application. It's up to you to chose the one that fits your needs.

Regards,

David.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from a Linux [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) and use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).