# How do I remove the Partition on my C Drive and merge the data without losing any?

Tags: partitioning

I used a Disk cloning device to clone my C Drive because it was running out of space. I used a 2 tb hard drive to upgrade to however the Cloning unit but only copied the 1 tb onto the drive leaving a empty 1 tb partition left. I formatted the partition and loaded some data on it but then realized I would like the C Drive to be a one partition, 2 tb drive. How do I remove the partition without losing the data on it?

Comment: If you delete the partition then you will lose data on that partition.  You can merge an empty partition ( depending on its location of course ) with an existing partition with data.  Which partition are you trying to remove exactly?  Why don't you simply extend the data partition to span the entire disk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge 3 NTFS partitions into 2 (Win XP) without reinstalling](http://superuser.com/questions/35774/merge-3-ntfs-partitions-into-2-win-xp-without-reinstalling), [Merging two partitions](http://superuser.com/questions/108141/merging-two-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted bootdisk. It's a small Linux Distribution with gparted app on it, you can install it on a USB thumbdrive and boot from there.
Once on the GUI, you can graphically add/delete and merge partitions withouth loosing data. Of course, a data backup is always recommended but I've never had a problem with this app.

[Gparted Site](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)